# Difference between typeScript compiler run commands

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was getting an error (Property 'find' does not exist on type 'IVehicle[]') on my .find() even after changed my target to "ES6" when trying to compile my file with "tsc script.ts" on console. I tried to run "npx -p typescript tsc" i got no error.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: `tsc <filename>` *ignores* your tsconfing file. [It's documented behaviour](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by @VLAZ, `tsc <filename>` ignores tsconfig file. Details about tsc CLI options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).